# repeater and ajax function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to get order id and put it in repeater data(repeater has other product info). I have written ajax function and it works fine with button click but I have no idea how to make it so it can load with each item in repeater so I can display order id with each item. I know, it can be done by getting same order id with other info in repeater but it is my requirement, please help.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function getOrder(id) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page2.aspx/getOrderID",
       data:  '{  id:"' + id + '"  }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {

   document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = response.d; 


}
</script>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold = "true" /><br />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
 <span id="span1" class="ajaxcall"></span>  
         <br/>
        <%#Eval("Name") %> - <%#Eval("Price") %><br />

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFooter" runat="server" Font-Bold = "true" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: cant you just get the orderid along with the repeater data?

Comment: No, as I have already mentioned, I need to get it from AJAX and display

Comment: So what do you need to pass to the ajax call? Order's name, date?

Comment: I have already passed id in getOrder(), it returns me a string(orderid). I have to show orderid for each item in repeater. Is it possible? I dont know how to pass function for each item?

Comment: where are you getting the id that you're passing in the getOrder method??

Comment: Well, I tried it like  <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" 
    onclick = "getOrder( 'Order001')" /> .. it worked

Comment: I tried to use ItemDataBound of repeater like:   Literal.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>getOrder('" + ID +  "');</script>";   .. it trigger the ajax function but I cannot print the returned data in repeater because each item in repeater has different id!!

Comment: what i mean is, is the Id 'Order001' hardcoded or is it going to come from somewhere?

Comment: It is not hardcoded... the problem for me is that how to print the returned data from ajax to repeater? Each item get different order id. I hope, u got what I mean?

Comment: what you can do is, In the document.ready event you can do $('#span1').load('somepage.aspx?id=' + id) and in this page in the page_load event you can get the orderID based on this id and print it using response.write. this way it will print orderId for all the rows